# Contents of variable set from for loop variable substitution refer to previous run in Windows batch script

Tags: batch-file

If this code is saved as the file tst.bat:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (%1) do (
    echo "%%~fa"
    set b=%%~fa
    echo "%b%"
)
```

And then invoked twice as follows, I'd expect to get this:

```
C:\Windows\Temp>tst.bat abc
"C:\Windows\Temp\abc"
"C:\Windows\Temp\abc"

C:\Windows\Temp>tst.bat xyz
"C:\Windows\Temp\xyz"
"C:\Windows\Temp\xyz"
```

But instead, I get this:

```
C:\Windows\Temp>tst.bat abc
"C:\Windows\Temp\abc"
""

C:\Windows\Temp>tst.bat xyz
"C:\Windows\Temp\xyz"
"C:\Windows\Temp\abc"
```

Do I have the wrong expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once upon a time, somebody wrote a great intro to the answer I'm about to give, but I can't find it. Basically, if you want to have variables inside the `for` loop update with the loop, you need to use delayedexpansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (%1) do (
    echo "%%~fa"
    set b=%%~fa
    echo "!b!"
)
```